# How to assert exceptions with Bddfy

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I am trying to use Test Stack Bddfy with MSTest and am running into an interesting issue. I have a piece of code where I am expecting an exception to be thrown. I am specifying that in MSTest tests and they are rightly passing. However Bddfy sees that exception as a problem and shows failing test in it's Html report. My method is simple

```
        [TestMethod, ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException))]
        public void Run()
        {
            this.BDDfy();
        }
```

How can I tell Bddfy that I am expecting exception of some type in this test?

I could not find Bddfy tag here so just tagging with MsTest.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I found this Q&A on their web page, check it out. Hope it helps!
https://github.com/TestStack/TestStack.BDDfy/issues/14

Answer (score 0):

An example showing Given, When, and Then syntax for an exception with BBDfy.

```
public class ExampleExceptionTest
{
    private Exception _exception;
    private readonly Sut _sut;

    public ExampleExceptionTest()
    {
        _sut = new Sut();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Updating_ItemDoesNotExist_Throws()
    {
        this.Given(_ => GivenSomething())
            .When(_ => WhenWeCallUpdateWithExpectedException<ApplicationException>())
            .Then(_ => ThenExceptionMessageIs("Could not update as item does not exist"))
            .BDDfy();
    }

    private void GivenSomething()
    {
        //Setup here - Assign
    }

    private void ThenExceptionMessageIs(string exceptionMessage)
    {
        //Verify Exception's message - Assert
        _exception.Message.ShouldBe(exceptionMessage);
    }

    private void WhenWeCallUpdateWithExpectedException<T>() where T : Exception
    {
        //Do something - Act
        _exception = Assert.Throws<T>(() => _sut.Update());
    }
}
```